# How to use Ascending Descending in JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a repository implemented as :

```
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item,Long > { ...
```

Within here I have a method as:

```
Page<Item> findAllOrderByCreateDateDesc(PageRequest pageRequest);
```

I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property desc found for type ZonedDateTime! Traversed path:
```

However if I add the By as:

```
Page<Item> findAllByOrderByCreateDateDesc(PageRequest pageRequest);
```

I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least 1 parameter(s) provided but only 0 parameter(s) present in query.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:136)
```

Seems like I should be writing this as:

```
findAllByOrderByCreateDateDesc
```

Why am I getting parameter error? I don't want to have a where clause for this particular query.

Comment: I can't see any difference between the two `findAllByOrderByCreateDateDesc(...)`

Comment: Why you don’t use sort option from page request?

Comment: try using a custom query. It's usually the easiest way to solve problems caused by some minor ambiguities

Comment: can you provide the code for your  Item entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a Pageable instead of a PageRequest in the repository method:

```
Page<Item> findAllByOrderByCreateDateDesc(Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Yep Lemmy this works, thanks. Odd with PageRequest the error wasn't very helpful in debugging.